# jquery load html file containing javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I tried to load an HTML file containing javascript code, the page doesn't display correctly.
Is there a way to load correctly this page?

PS: I used FireFox to test

```
<div class="mydiv"></div>

 var path = myHTMLWithJavaScript.html;

 $.get(path, function(data) {

    $(".mydiv").load(path);
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use `$.get` or  `$(".mydiv").load(path);` not both

Also,

```
var path = myHTMLWithJavaScript.html;
```

should be (notice double quotes)

```
var path = "myHTMLWithJavaScript.html";
```

and make sure that this file is present in the same directory as your page

Comment: I forget to add double quotes but those are present in the code.
I get the same issue when I use only "load"

Comment: The page is not completly displayed.

Comment: If the page you are loading is not being displayed properly then there is a possibility that the HTML is broken in that page. Can you share link or code to your pages?

Comment: In fact I have to two versions of this HTML page. The first one doesn't contain javascript and it display correctly. 

Unfortunately I cannot share it, as it said I should analyse the javascript code, maybe there is something wrong within it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are tyring to load JavaScript File / Code it is better to use `$.getScript`. More information can be found here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: That I see,   $.getScript is only use for javascript file, not for html file?

Comment: @Jils: You are right. `$.getScript` will load JavaScript code and then execute it in current DOM's context.

Comment: But I don't understand how to use is it in my case? I don't have javascript file but only html file.

Comment: @Jils: If you have an html file which also contains JavaScript code then `$.load` should work fine here. Try to alert some string in your JavaScript Code in your html file and if you don't see an alert then there must be something wrong with your JavaScript code (maybe type attribute on script tag has wrong value)

Comment: I will proceed an analyse to check if there someting wrong in the code